# Show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_t d \lambda_n = \frac{1}{|t|^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d \lambda^n$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{B}^n$-measurable. For $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, define $f_t(x) = f(tx)$.

Prove that if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d \lambda_n$ is defined then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_t d \lambda_n = \frac{1}{|t|^n} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d \lambda_n$. Here $\lambda_n$ is the Lebesgure measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to use Tonelli and Fubini's theorems, but for that I need $f \geq 0$ or $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f| d \lambda_n < \infty$, none of which are given. So I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: Can't you just substitute $x$ with $y = tx$ ? Then $dy = |t|^n dx$ and thus
$$
\int_{\mathcal{R}^n}f(tx)dx = \int_{\mathcal{R}^n}f(tx) \frac{|t|^n}{|t|^n} dx \\
\int_{\mathcal{R}^n}f(tx) \frac{1}{|t|^n} |t|^n dx = \int_{\mathcal{R}^n}f(y) \frac{1}{|t|^n} dy
$$

If you can use integration by substitution

Comment: @justabit: You can't use substitution here.

Comment: why not? it's a diffeomorphism and the derivative is well defined.

Comment: @justabit: The proof of the substitution theorem whenever $f$ is not continuous is  rather demanding and requiers deeper knowledge in measure theory.  Taking into account the question of the OP, I would be very surprised that he already proved this theorem, and thus, I would be very surprised that he can use it a priori.

Comment: Ah yes. And if one wanted to extend the proof one would have to look at the simple functions and then extend it just as you mentioned.

Comment: @justabit: in this case yes, but in the general case it is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For the kind of exercise, the proof always goes the same. Prove it first for simple function, then for positive function using approximation by increasing simple function, and then for measurable function.

- **Step 1 :** For $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_n}(x)$ being simple, then

\begin{align*}
\int f(tx)\lambda _n(\mathrm d x)&=\sum_{i=1 }^na_i\int\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}(tx)\lambda _n(\mathrm d x)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\int \boldsymbol 1_{t^{-1}A_n}(x)\,\mathrm d x\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^na_im(t^{-1}A_i)\\
&=\frac{1}{|t|^n} \sum_{i=1}^na_im(A_i)\\
&=\frac{1}{|t|^n}\int f(x)\lambda _n(\mathrm d x).
\end{align*}

- **Step 2** If $f\geq 0$, there is a sequence of simple function $(\varphi _n)$ s.t. $\varphi _n\nearrow f$. I let you conclude using Monotone Convergence Theorem.
- **Step 3** Take $f^+(x):= f(x)\vee 0$ and $f^-(x)=-(f(x)\wedge 0)$ (where $a\vee b$ denote the maximum of $a$ and $b$ and $a\wedge b$ denotes the minimum). Then $f^\pm \geq 0$ and $f=f^+-f^-$. You can then conclude using step $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(x)=tx$, $t \neq 0$. Then we use the results on image measures to assert that:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(tx)\lambda^n(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(g(x))\lambda^n(dx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)\lambda^n_g(dy)$$
where
$$\lambda_g^n(B)=\lambda^n(g^{-1}(B))=\lambda^n(t^{-1}B)=|t|^{-n}\lambda^n(B) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
thus
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(tx)\lambda^n(dx)=|t|^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(y)\lambda^n(dy)$$

Comment: I would be very surprised that the OP can use $\int f(g(x))\lambda ^n(dx)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(y)\lambda _g^n(dx)$... the proof of this result is rather demanding and requiers some good knowledge in measure theory... Taking into account the question of the OP, I would be very surprised that he already proved this result...

Comment: @Surb yes it's a possibility. I wanted to write this anyway to complement your answer